# GP faults in x86 recovery

Tags: x86, automated-tests, general-protection-fault

I would like to automate some test cases running on IA-32 x86 architecture based target, Some of these test cases generates a general protection Fault ( expected result as a part of the validation process). I would like to know if there is a way to recover from this fault and proceed with the rest of the test cases. If not what are other potential way for the automation of the tests?

Comment: Yes, but depends on your environment.

Comment: I am working on ubuntu 64-bit , and using GNU toolchain.

Comment: The safe bet is to run the test in a separate process (you can simply `fork()`) which you can `ptrace` to detect and analyze the fault.

Comment: I am runing the tests on a target hardware ( Quark Se based board- with an x86 core ) , I have to flash the tests on the board and see results through a serial port, I want to recover from a fault on the hardware...

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you said you were running ubuntu. So, you have processes and ptrace. What's the problem?

Comment: i am developing on linux Ubuntu but i am running my code on a hardware target (Interl Quark_se) .. sorry got you wrong

Comment: Assuming your code is running completely on the bare metal, no OS of any sort, then you'd need install a GP fault handler in the IDT and that handler would then have to somehow resume execution in a way that would allow the next test to execute. Exactly how you'd do that depends on a lot of details, like whether your code is running in real mode or protected mode.

Comment: Hello @RossRidge , I am running in protected mode.. my code is running on the bare metal, and I already installed a GP fault handler, when a GP fault happends  the handler is excuted but I cant think of a proper mechanism to resume tests from the handler ... for example should I jump to the next test function from my handler and modify my EIP, CS, etc ... or what do you think should i do from the handler ?

Comment: Is your test code running in ring 0 or ring 3?

Comment: @RossRidge depends.. I have some tests that have tasks running in ring 3 and some in ring 0 , as I mentioned I am doing some hardware validation so for example I have a test that do a permission violations "unprivileged Call from a task in ring 3 to a task in ring 0 " and as expected I get a GP fault , and then the handler get excuted ... at this point I want to  save the test result "Ex: saying Test failed due to permission violation" and want to figure out someway to proced with next tests.

Comment: Yah. that really complicates things. If it were all ring 3 code I would suggest maybe implementing a Unix-like signal interface and using `longjmp` in the signal handler to abort the test and move onto the next one. With it mixed like that it depends a lot on how you're actually running the tests, and from the sounds of things you may need multiple different strategies. At least two, one to handle the ring 0 tests and another for the ring 3 ones.